# async await promisse error in react native , how to solve?

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise, react-hooks

Im getting the following error:

`'await' has no effect on the type of this expression.ts`

What I'm trying to call is call the api by the function `loginuser()` and then I want it to get the information that I stored after a sucessfull attempt of login. I'm using Async storage to store and to get this storage.

```
import { loginUser } from '../controller/userAction';
         ...
         JSX components 
            ...
    const loginHandle = async(userName,password) => async() => {      
      
      else{      
        try {
          await loginUser(
            userName,
            password,
            setShowLoader)

           signIn(userName,password);

        }catch (error) {
          console.log(error.message)
        }                         
      }      
  }
```

In my `loginuser` I call the API and store user information
at my sign in I want to get the information that I stored before (because of this Im trying to use `async/await`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

await is not a function, it's a operate and you use it something like this.

```
await loginUser(....)
await singUp(...)
```

Comment: You are right , but when i try to use like this it says that my func loginuser `'await' has no effect on the type of this expression.` , and it go to my func signin first and I need my login func first, do you know a way to solve it ?

Comment: I would need more information about your code to help you with that, can you edit the question and add the missing parts ?

Comment: I edited and put more info about my code , the func `loginuser` is an axios call ,and the sign up is where im trying to get the information from the axios (Im storing with async storage)